# Probability Question on time overlap

Tags: probability

Alice and Bob work at the same place for 30 minutes and 45 minutes respectively. They are free to choose a starting time anytime between 8:00am and 9:00am. What is the probability that they will see each other during their shifts?

I'm not sure if I approach this question correctly. I would answer this question as follows. In the case of when they don't meet, there are two possible scenarios:

1. Alice clocks in first and finishes before Bill starts, which means Alice starts at time `a` between 8:00am and 8:30am and Bill starts at time `b>=a+30`. I am not sure how to calculate the probability for this case due to the dependence and the continuity of time (e.g. I'm pretty sure I can't just have 30 separate cases and calculate the probability for when Alice starts at 8:00, 8:01, ..., 8:30. Right?)
2. Bob clocks in first and finishes before Alice starts, which means Bob starts at time `b` between 8:00am and 8:15am and Alice starts at time `a>=b+45`. Not sure how to calculate the probability for this either for similar reasons.

How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Try drawing a square, with the x-axis representing Alice's arrival time and the y-axis representing Bob's arrival time.  Then shade the area with arrival times such that they see each other during their shifts.  Hopefully, this will make it clear how to calculate the probability.

Comment: @jbowman thank you! so then I draw two lines b=a+30 and b=a-45, shade the area in between, and get the answer 27/32. Does this sound right? (not sure if I'm allowed to check my answer on this platform)

Comment: Yes, you got it!

Comment: Great, thank you so much @jbowman!